# Ruby on Rails - Drop down menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, menu

A noob here. I've only just started to learn ROR, and I'm having a problem with a drop down menu, that allows the user to select a project from a database. I have the drop down menu working, however instead of the project names, it shows something like Project:0xb61fbdbc.

```
    <%= f.label :project_name %><br />
    <%= f.select(:project_name, Project.all, :prompt => "Select a Project") %>
```

I have searched,and searched and had no luck. Hopefully someone can help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should help, provided that you have a `name` attribute in your `Project` model:

```
<%= f.select(:project_name, Project.all.map {|p| [p.name,p.id]}, :prompt => "Select a Project") %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew it would be something simple :)

Comment: You can find more on select boxes in form builders here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease. Can you accept the answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: I noticed that it would now show the name of the project, but when I submitted, it displayed as the id of that project name. I changed the code you suggested to 

<%= f.select(:project_name, Project.all.map {|p| [p.project_name]}, :prompt => "Select a Project") %>

Which now works perfectly, Thank you.

Comment: This really depends on what exactly you want to be submitted from the select box. Submitting names from a single selection box is OK when the names are unique, but generally you'd want to use unique attributes such as IDs.